# Get articles intro-image in Module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I'm new to Joomla and in the progress of developing a little module, that should display the intro-image of the article that is shown by the "com_article" component. 
The module should be a widget in a kind of sidebar, that's what it is for.
I already searched the web and played around with `JSite`, but didn't get the data i was looking for.

How do i get the images uri?

Kind regards,

André

Comment: can you provide some code that you have already tried?

Comment: I tried to get the instance of com_content via `JFactory::getApplication()->getParams("com_content")->getInstance()->get("float_fulltext")`, but i think those are the global Parameters of the Component. I don't know how i can get the Parameter of the current sites instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer:

```
$articleId = JFactory::getApplication()->getRouter()->getVar("id");

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select($db->quoteName('images'))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
        ->where('id = '. $db->Quote($articleId));

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
$images = json_decode($result);
```